# Why are there differences in 2 Smog Check VIRs?

Tags: emissions

I had 2 Smog Check Vehicle Inspection Reports within a week performed at different stations. I see differences in both the "Inspection Reason" and the "Software Version/EIS Number" plus the "Exhaust" description is "Single" on both reports but the car has dual exhaust pipes. Do these differences matter? Thank you.

car: 1991 Cadillac Eldorado; reason for 1st test: DMV-required biennial;
reason for 2nd test: failed the 1st test.

Comment: I don't think the inspection reasons matters, i.e  biannual,  change of ownership.  What kind of vehicle is it

Answer (score 1):

The reason can be many : customer request, required (annual) test, Police request etc, it won't change the values. Idem for the exhaust single / double though they should have recorded this correctly and it also depends on the system as some cars have separate pipes for each bank, others have 2 pipes that only split at the rear which is often down to the visual balanced look...

The software version may give different results as the two stations used different machines. The authorities would know what the differences (if any) in the software will do to the results.

As you don't provide any of the results then we cannot say if it matters, at the moment probably not, why did you have two tests close together ? Police request or failed the first test?